# How to drop the first row number column pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

This question may sound similar to other questions posted, but I'm posting this after searching long for this exact solution.

So, I've a JSON from which I'm creating a pandas dataframe:

```
col_list = ["allocation","completion_date","has_expanded_access"]
final_data = dict((k,d[k]) for k in (col_list) if k in d)
a = json_normalize(final_data)
```

[image]

And then this:

[image]

I tried saving with:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

And

```
df = df.rename_axis(None)
```

As suggested on few answers, but of no use, when I try to save it, this default first column containing row index comes with header as blank (null), even if I try to drop, it doesn't work. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

`df.to_csv('df_name.csv', sep = ';', encoding = 'cp1251', index = False)`

to save df without indices.

Or change index column with

`df.set_index('col_name')`

Comment: Why didn't this work: df = df.reset_index(drop=True)?

Comment: With ```index = False``` you able to drop indices

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save the dataframe as csv file then you can do this:

```
df.to_csv(filename, index=False)
```